# Differences between wpdb->get_results() and wpdb->query()

Tags: query, wpdb

Who can explain me the differences between `wpdb->get_results()` and `wpdb->query()` in making generic queries to wordpress db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference, if you want to call it that, is that the [`query()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1535) is the most generalized method to do queries with [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), the [`get_results()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1946) method on the other hand is a specific method, which [does make use of the `query()` method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1950) to retrieve the specific results of this method and then does some work on the output.

Answer (score 6):

It is the output juggling that `get_results()` does. If you [look at the source for `get_results()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php), the work of the query is done by `query()`.  Eveything after that is just "casting" the results to the data type specified by the `$output` argument.

> ```
> 1946          public function get_results( $query = null, $output = OBJECT ) {
> 1947                  $this->func_call = "\$db->get_results(\"$query\", $output)";
> 1948  
> 1949                  if ( $query )
> 1950                          $this->query( $query );
> 1951                  else
> 1952                          return null;
> ```